# Error when move or delete file on ext4 in dpkg info directory

Tags: linux, permissions, apt, ext4, dpkg

There is a troublemaking empty file (md5sums of kernel 4.19.1) left 
on my ubuntu system, with has strange owner/group/date/attributes

How to fix or workaround this defect file?

```
$ uname -a
Linux olly-ryzen-pc1 4.20.10-042010-generic #201902150516 SMP Fri 
Feb 15 10:19:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**stat**

```
$ stat /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.md5sums 
  Datei: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.md5sums 
  Größe: 0             Blöcke: 0          EA Block: 4096   Normale 
leere Datei <= empty file
Gerät: 802h/2050d    Inode: 27918873    Verknüpfungen: 1 
Zugriff: (5625/-rwS-w-r-t)  Uid: (477987903/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (3699747887/ 
UNKNOWN) 
Zugriff    : 2381-05-02 11:29:39.163881368 +0100 
Modifiziert: 2293-06-01 00:54:46.455862499 +0100 
Geändert   : 2167-05-10 21:19:01.867729249 +0100 
 Geburt    : -
```

**lsattr**

```
$ lsattr /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.md5sums
lsattr: Keine Daten verfügbar Beim Lesen der Flags von /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.md5sums
```

**apt, dpkg**

This file can't changed or deleted (remove/purge 4.19.1), but 
troubles apt-get to install applications.

--fix-broken or --reinstall dpkg  exit also with 'not allowed' message.

Cannot be deleted.
Die Control-Info-Datei »/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.
19.1-041901-generic.md5sums« kann nicht gelöscht werden: Vorgang 
nicht zulässig

**chmod -st, chown root:root**

No changes.

**rm -f**

No.

**live USB**

Also tried a boot of ubuntu (install 4.18) from USB-Stick to repair, but:

`sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sba2`   does not report an error

`sudo badblocks -vsn /dev/sda2`  reports 0 bad blocks

and `rm`, `chmod`, `chown`: same behaivior as above ..

Only to compare, here is a neighbor file:

```
$ stat /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-sound-base.md5sums 
  Datei: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-sound-base.md5sums 
  Größe: 545           Blöcke: 8          EA Block: 4096   Normale Datei 
Gerät: 802h/2050d    Inode: 27269131    Verknüpfungen: 1 
Zugriff: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root) 
Zugriff    : 2019-02-03 16:56:08.943545720 +0100 
Modifiziert: 2015-07-31 05:42:23.000000000 +0200 
Geändert   : 2018-05-22 01:20:37.178864616 +0200 
 Geburt    : - 

$ lsattr /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.list
--------------e--- 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.list
```

Comment: Have you tried `mv` to rename the file?

Comment: sudo mv ..md5sums ..md5sums.ren => 'Operation not permitted'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `fsck` does not find anything wrong, you may need to use `debugfs` to clear the inode. Note that I last used `debugfs` years ago, so take care! Read the manpage first to see what's possible with this tool.

Boot from a rescue medium, and run

```
debugfs /dev/sda2
```

You can try to use debugfs's `rm` command to remove the file:

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.md5sums
```

(assuming that /dev/sda2 is mounted on `/`, not `/var`)

If that doesn't work, you might try freeing the inode. You already know the inode number (27918873) from the `stat` output. You can free the inode with:

```
freei 27918873
```

After manipulating the filesystem with `debugfs` I recommend running `fsck` again.

Comment: Thank you Wurtel, will check this out in the evening.

Comment: See result below.

Answer (score 0):

**Works!**

`debugfs: open -w /dev/sda2`

`debugfs: stat 27918873`

27918873: File not found by ext2_lookup

`debugfs: ncheck 27918873`

Inode        Pathname

27918873 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.md5sums

`debugfs: rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic.md5sums`

`debugfs: quit`

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ `sudo e2fsck /dev/sda2`

e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda2: clean, 367369/30498816 files, 20494756/121965056 blocks

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda2`

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes

Pass 2: Checking directory structure

Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity

Pass 4: Checking reference counts

Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sda2: 367369/30498816 files (2.1% non-contiguous), 20494756/121965056 blocks

*boot to main system*

olly@olly-ryzen-pc1:~$ `sudo apt-get purge`

Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig

Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.

Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig

Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT: linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic

0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 1 zu entfernen und 187 nicht aktualisiert.

1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.

Nach dieser Operation werden 8.626 kB Plattenplatz freigegeben.

Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j

(Lese Datenbank ... 207988 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)

**Entfernen von linux-image-unsigned-4.19.1-041901-generic (4.19.1-041901.201811041431) ...**

**DONE!** Finally! Thank you @wurtel a lot!

Comment: Shall I `freei 27918873` after all?

Comment: `freei` shouldn't be needed if the `rm` succeeded. Please accept my answer as correct as it worked for you. (Although perhaps you can't as you don't have enough reputation yet?)

Comment: @Wurtel anyone who's asked a question can accept an answer on their question.